# Problems with quotes when writing javascript code in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, escaping, quotes

I wonder what's the best method for writing javascript code into a PHP variable?

Some times it might be quite long javascript code... Is there a way without escaping all quotes?

```
<?php
echo '
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

a_div.innerHTML = '<iframe style="width:100%;height:300px;" id="iframe_upload" src="index.php">';

</script>'

?>
```

Comment: Doesn't your current code give you an `unexpected T_STRING` error? You need to change parts of it to: `a_div.innerHTML = \'<iframe style="width:100%;height:300px;" id="iframe_upload" src="index.php">\';` and `</script>';` (though this does escape quotes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). For example:

```
$var = EOF<<<
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
a_div.innerHTML = '<iframe style="width:100%;height:300px;" id="iframe_upload" src="index.php">';
</script>
EOF;
```

The `EOF` can be any arbitrary string you want, it just has to come directly after the `<<<` delimiter and match on both sides of the string you want to create.

Comment: Important: heredoc syntax in PHP acts like double quotes, meaning variables are expanded and backslash sequences are interpreted.  If you want the text to be read literally, use nowdoc syntax instead (i.e. say `'EOF'<<<` instead of `EOF<<<`.  nowdoc syntax was introduced in PHP 5.3.0

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple don't mix PHP code and HTML/JavaScript and if you need to do so, end the PHP block with `?>` and open it again with `<?php` after your HTML/JS block.

If you need it inside a variable, you could either use output buffering which is kind of messy though or use [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)/[Nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) strings:

```
<?php
$foo = <<<FOOBAR
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    a_div.innerHTML = '<iframe style="width:100%;height:300px;" id="iframe_upload" src="index.php">';
</script>

FOOBAR;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

a_div.innerHTML = '<iframe style="width:100%;height:300px;" id="iframe_upload" src="index.php">';

</script>
```

And in case you need php in there somewhere:

```
a_div.innerHTML = '<iframe style="width:<?php echo $width; ?>;height:300px;" id="iframe_upload" src="index.php">';
```